# CSS 3 animation effects are not working in IE

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, css, effects

I am trying to include this beautiful list of animation effects from 
[Liffect - Effect for Lists](http://ademilter.com/lab/liffect/) into my ASP.NET application.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <ul effects="pageTop">
            <li>
                <img src="Images/1.jpeg" alt="Car" /></li>
            <li>
                <img src="Images/2.jpeg" alt="Car" /></li>
            <li>
                <img src="Images/3.jpeg" alt="Car" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">            
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("ul[effects] li").each(function (i) {
                $(this).attr("style", "-webkit-animation-delay:" + i * 300 + "ms;"
                        + "-moz-animation-delay:" + i * 300 + "ms;"
                        + "-o-animation-delay:" + i * 300 + "ms;"
                        + "animation-delay:" + i * 300 + "ms;");
                if (i == $("ul[effects] li").size() - 1) {
                    $("ul[effects]").addClass("play")
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</form>
```

Here you can find the [JS Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/furqansafdar/ukD6X/9/).

After struggling few hours, I have just noticed that this is working in `Firefox 16.x` but not in `IE 9`. It seems some kind of `CSS 3` problem but not sure exactly where is it wrong. Please help making it fully cross-browser compatible (`IE`, `Firefox`, `Chrome` etc.)

I would also appreciate for letting me know about some good resources for cross-browser compatible `CSS 3` hacks for `HTML 5`.

Comment: What versions of IE do do you want to support?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, its IE 9. Updated my question.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=css3%20animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IE8 and below you won't have any support for CSS3. Check [this nice reference](http://caniuse.com/) to see if what you want to use is available in major browsers.

EDIT to your last update: Animation is not supported in IE9

Comment: Animation is supported in IE9, the reference which i used is working in IE9 but when i am trying to use it in ASP.Net or JSFiddler it is not working. See my edited question.

Comment: If you're using somebodyelses fiddle, check the left column for extra scripts or resources. Most likely that code is using a library to add support for IE9 because it doesn't have it by default.

Answer (score 1):

Best you take a look at this regarding CSS3 Animation With jQuery Fallbacks:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh304380.aspx

And also http://modernizr.com/ for "cross-browser compatible CSS 3 hacks for HTML 5"

Answer (score 0):

What ever css you used is CSS3 IE7 and IE8 will not support css3 properties.